# Write back data to the source in Project Siena app

Tags: siena, project-siena

I have a requirement to save data added by the user to a server. Is there any way to write back data to the source? or to somehow send the data to an azure server in project siena

Comment: Sorry but this question doesn't make sense. What do you mean with source? Siena is a database abstraction layer in Java, and I don't know about anyone running it on Azure, that would be a surprise.

Comment: I meant Microsoft Project Siena

Comment: Oh I see ;-) the tag Siena is for the old Java project with the same name